# Freemarker break line

Tags: java, freemarker, xdocreport

I have such code in my template as merge field

```
[#list testList as tl] ${tl} [/#list]
```

but all `tl` printed near each other, but I have to print all `tl` on their own lines. If i will do like this

```
[#list testList as tl] 
${tl} 
[/#list]
```

I got an error that freemarker expects string literal or parameter, but got `[/#list]`

Comment: you can use `<br>` before data print.

Comment: @user3145373ツ that won't work because I am not converting to html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way. Instead of one merge field I created three that looks like this:
`[#list testList as tl]`
`${tl}`
`[/#list]`